# Alamofire completion handler not called

Tags: swift, alamofire, apple-developer

For the below code processResponse not called. From Mac App. I'm calling a REST Web service API

I also get error like, but request sent

2018-11-09 21:04:43.211276+0530 Project[11337:1470266] SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=22 cs_flags=20, pid=11337
2018-11-09 21:04:43.211383+0530 Project [11337:1470266] SecTaskCopyDebugDescription: Project[11337]/0#-1 LF=0

```
Alamofire.request("http://192.168.1.140:8080/api", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON(completionHandler: processResponse)



func processResponse(completion: DataResponse<Any>) {
    print("*********************RESPONSE came")

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by adding **Team** and **Signing Certificate** to **Signing (Debug)**. Warnings went away in my case.

You can also double check that System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Firewall > Firewall Options > **Automatically allow downloaded signed software to receive incoming connections** is enabled.